# z-index для select-option элементов

Tags: html, css

У меня есть проблема. Есть такой код:

```css
.hover {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hover:hover {
  height: 100px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover"></div>
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">123131231232131</option>
  <option value="">131231231312122</option>
  <option value="">31231313131313</option>
  <option value="">13131313131314</option>
  <option value="">51232131313123</option>
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если навести на верхний блок, он увеличивает высоту и перекрывает select. Но, если открыт список option-ов, он перекрывает этот блок. Как это можно исправить?

P.S. z-index для этого не подходит

Upd: Исправить то, что список option-ов над блоком hover, необходимо что бы он был под ним 
Upd2: Сейчас это выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо что бы список option-ов был под блоком

Comment: Исправить что?????  А каков должен быть конечный результат...?

Comment: Обязательно ли абсолютное позиционирование?

Comment: почему нельзя использовать `z-index`?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, потому что он не срабатывает

Comment: @RuslanSemenov да, оно обязательно

Comment: перекрывает, потому что select в данном случае по умолчанию имеет position: static. Скорее всего в вашем случае необходимо использовать js для кастомизации селекта

Comment: @Gettysburg посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Добавил скрин того, как это в Вашем ответе и описание того, как должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант select обернуть в div (должно помочь при изменении размера hover )

Comment: Все равно, блок с option виден и перекрывает div

Answer (score 0):

Не то позиционируете. Если уже привязаны к абсолюту.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hover {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: ralative;
  transition: height 200ms;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hover:hover {
  height: 100px;
}

select {
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover"></div>
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">123131231232131</option>
  <option value="">131231231312122</option>
  <option value="">31231313131313</option>
  <option value="">13131313131314</option>
  <option value="">51232131313123</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но, так наверх поднялся и select, а нужно наоборот

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hover {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:10;
}

.hover:hover {
  height: 100px;
}

.hover:hover ~ #select{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#select {
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover"></div>
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="">123131231232131</option>
  <option value="">131231231312122</option>
  <option value="">31231313131313</option>
  <option value="">13131313131314</option>
  <option value="">51232131313123</option>
</select>
```